# Ember, working with a model

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I'm confused about how to set up retrieve information from my (dynamic) model in Ember.js

Here is my model (works so far):

```
App.Router.map(function() {
        this.resource('calendar', { path: '/calendar/:currentMonth'});
});

App.CalendarRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    var obj = {
       daysList: calendar.getDaysInMonth("2013", params.currentMonth),
       currentMonth: params.currentMonth
    };
    return obj;
  }
});
```

I just want to get back the 'currentMonth' attribute:

```
App.CalendarController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  next: function() {
    console.log(this.get('currentMonth'));
  }
});
```

But I am getting an "undefined" error.

Do I have to explicitly declare my model (Ember.model.extend()) in order to get and set values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some [conventions](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/) that you might not be aware of in regards to setting a `Model` into a `Controller`.

In a `Route`, model can be any object or collection of objects you define. There is a huge deal of conventions that apply and for most cases, you don't have to specify anything as it uses the names of various objects to guide itself on building the query and a set the content of your controller, however, in your particular code, you are return `obj` as the model.

Ember provides a hook called `setupController` that will set this object into your controller's `content` property. Example:

```
App.CalendarRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    var obj = {
       daysList: calendar.getDaysInMonth("2013", params.currentMonth),
       currentMonth: params.currentMonth
    };
    return obj;
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
     // model in this case, should be the instance of your "obj" from "model" above
     controller.set('content', model);
  }
});
```

With that said, you should try `console.log(this.get('content.currentMonth'));`