# Ember.js Router/controller properties

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

I'm trying to wrap my head around the `model` property or a route vs. the `content` property of the controller. If you set the `model` property in a route, does this automatically set it to the `content` property in a generated controller.

Also, I think the `content` property of the controller allows you to access the attributes of that object in the template, is that true?

I read the docs and still am having trouble digesting some of these conventions.

Comment: Have you seen any of the introduction screencasts that show how to use routes/views/controllers/models? I did one a month ago that covers the basics in 36 minutes http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2013/03/02/emberjs-rc1-introduction-screencast/

Comment: I haven't seen that one. I watched this one (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7O9X5oeAJm4) and it really helped me understand the overall structure of things. I'll check this one out. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As answered [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886841/ember-working-with-a-model/15887046#15887046), `Ember.Route` has a `model` function which allows you to set an object or a collection of objects as the model of that route. Routes that deal with a single object should have a controller that extends `Ember.ObjectController` while routes that deal with a collection of objects should have a controller that extends `Ember.ArrayController`.
Subsequently, in the `Route` workflow, the data coming from the `model` hook is set into the controller's `content` property via `setupController` hook.

The routes have their own workflow to setup their controllers, so by default this method will be called and populate the content with the model. Consider the following:

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/N3Z3h/)

```
App.Email = DS.Model.extend({
    address: DS.attr('string'),
    isActive: DS.attr('boolean')
});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('emails', function() {
        this.route('email', {path: ':email_id'});
    });
});

App.EmailsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Email.find();
    }
});
App.EmailRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return App.Email.find(params.email_id);
    }
});

App.EmailsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();
App.EmailController = Ember.ObjectController.extend();
```

The framework should generate the default code for these routes in order to setup the controller, which would look like this (and you can override if you want):

```
App.EmailsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    ...
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.set('content', model);
    }
    ...
});
```

There are cases (see question/answer linked above) in which you may need/want to override these methods to do something different than the default functionality, for example:

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/vJENg/)

```
App.EmailsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return [{id: 1, address: 'other@email.com'}];
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        // here, controller is whatever controller this route needs
        // by conventions, it knows it should be EmailsController
        // of the type ArrayController
        // model is whatever was returned by the model function above

        // the content is a "bag" which can be filled with a model or any
        // other object you need. Just keep in mind your view layer will
        // be referring to this object later on
        controller.set('content', model);

        // you can set other properties of the controller here too
        controller.set('applyFilter', true);
    }
});
```

Now the templates will be able to access the data in the controller. The example below iterates through a collection of objects (`App.Email`) in the `EmailsController`. Any public attribute in this collection or in its child objects are accessible here, one example is `{{email.address}}`:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="emails">
    <ul>
    {{#each email in controller}}
        <li>
            {{#linkTo emails.email email}}
                {{email.address}}
            {{/linkTo}}
        </li>    
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

Note that the template is not talking directly to the model, but rather to the `content`, which was assigned with data from the model. Like I said, you can stash any object in the content or model via routes, so you're not tied to use `DS.Model` nor the architecture is strongly coupled.

If this model, instead of `App.Email` type, had a different type with different attributes, it would also be accessible here, with limitations tho. If an attribute of the model is a collection, it cannot be accessed through index (e.g. `{{email.messages[0].body}}` wouldn't work). The best course of action in this case, would be a computed property in the controller which would give you direct access to the first item of the messages collection of the email, if it had one.

Comment: This is the best answer I've seen! Thanks so much for taking the time to explain.

Comment: your answer explain it so much better than the guides